# Custom Controls in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

this question is propably easy to answer, but I really don't know what I should look for in that matter =)

I try to explain it.

Before I came to classic JSF I worked with a similar technology (based on JSF.. kind of...) There we had Custom Controls. Basically it was a module, a xhtml file. There you could define some areas which where to be filled in the xhtml file in which you use this module.

For example, I want to create a taskbar. This taskbar is used on every page I have. I have some controls in it, some predefined buttons, styles and so on. But I want to put some custom buttons in it depending on which site I am. Is this done with facets? It was called similar in the other technology, but I can't find it here. Back then we have put the control into the page and then inside the tag we could define something to put our other components into that module.

I hope you can understand what I mean with that. I am a bit at a lack of words here, which is the reason I havn't found the solution until now =)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The linked duplicate must give you a lot of keywords and examples of what you could be looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I use ui:composition and ui:decorate for that.